# OneDrive stopped synchronizing

Tags: sync, onedrive

I used SkyDrive for a long time, I have 2 computers linked to my account. Since it changed to OneDrive, I place documents in my Skydrive folder in vain, it doesn't sync to my other computer. The icon shows OneDrive label, the folder is named SkyDrive. It should detect changes immediately but it shows that my files are fully synched.

The menu item Examine sync problems is inactive. In Task manager, the program runs as *SkyDrive.exe*.

What should I check?

Answer (score 0):

After Windows 8.1 update, the folder should rename automatically. Otherwise, check this article which describes how renaming can work. http://www.windowsobserver.com/2014/04/06/rename-skydrive-folder-to-onedrive-after-windows-8-1-update-installation/